# Remove [app] questions from active

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stackapps

Now we have a special app tab, shouldn't the [app] questions at least be given lower priority on the active tab, which is now for development?

Ideally it would be to have the ability to sort the app tab, by activity or votes.

Answer (score 2):

No, we still want people looking at updated app listings for vandalism and the like.

Plus I dislike the idea of having the active tab differ in meaning only on StackApps.  There's still something to be said for commonalities between the Stack Exchange network sites.

Comment: Can't they be moved to a subcategory of apps tab? The whole point of the apps tab is to seperate the apps and non-app questions.